# Get item count of a list<> using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-3.5

I want to query a List<> and find out how MANY items match the selection criteria.  using LINQ  and c# /.net 3.5.  How would I modify the query to return an int count.

```
var specialBook = from n in StoreDisplayTypeList 
                  where n.DisplayType=="Special Book" 
                  select n;
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
 var numSpecialBooks = StoreDisplayTypeList.Count(n => n.DisplayType == "Special Book");
```

This uses an overload of [`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) that takes a`Func<TSource, bool>`predicate to filter the sequence.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
int specialBookCount = (from n in StoreDisplayTypeList 
                        where n.DisplayType=="Special Book" 
                        select n).Count()
```

But if you need data as well, you might want to operate with IEnumerable. So, you can use your query and access Count() extension method whenever you want.

```
var specialBook = from n in StoreDisplayTypeList 
                  where n.DisplayType=="Special Book" 
                  select n;
int num = specialBook.Count();
```

Answer (score 7):

Just surround your query like this: `(from ... select n).Count()`.