# Count elements with int < 5 in List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, count

I have a `List<int>` and need to count how many elements with (value < 5) it has - how do I do this?

Comment: Yeesh! Someone spent a bunch of time downvoting 4 answers below.

Comment: @p.campbell - Yeah, whomever it was took offence to the extraneous `Where`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get item count of a list<> using Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853010/get-item-count-of-a-list-using-linq)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`Count()` has an overload accepting `Predicate<T>`:

```
int count = list.Count(x => x < 5);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx)

Answer (score 37):

Unlike other answers, this does it in one method call using this overload of the [count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
using System.Linq;

...

var count = list.Count(x => x < 5);
```

Note that since linq extension methods are defined in the `System.Linq` namespace you might need to add a using statement, and reference to `System.Core` if it's not already there (it should be).

---

See also: [Extension methods defined by the `Enumerable` class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx)

Comment: +1 because you were one minute earlier than the accepted answer of abatischchev ;)

Answer (score 18):

The shortest option:

```
myList.Count(v => v < 5);
```

This would also do:

```
myList.Where(v => v < 5).Count();
```

Comment: +1 I actually really like the later method here as they are pretty much equivalent performance wise and I think it's a little clearer what's going on here.

Answer (score 8):

```
int count = list.Count(i => i < 5);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
List<int> list = ...
int count = list.Where(x => x < 5).Count();
```

Answer (score 6):

Try -

```
var test = new List<int>();
test.Add(1);
test.Add(6);
var result =  test.Count(i => i < 5);
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
var count = myList.Where(x => x < 5).Count();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list.Where(x => x < 5).Count()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int c = myList.Where(x=>x<5).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int c = 0;
for (i = 0; i > list.Count; i++)
{
    // The "for" is check all elements that in list.
    if (list[i] < 5)
    {
        c = c + 1; // If the element is smaller than 5
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 For being the only answer that doesn't use LINQ. Although I would have preferred use of "foreach" instead of "for". Even better would be a generalized method that has a predicate as the parameter and can then be invoked using lambda notation.